# JQUERY undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined

I am getting "JQUERY undefined" error. Do you have any idea (code below).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="faturaYazici2" CodeBehind="faturaYazici2.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="JS/reset-fonts-grids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="JS/boxy/jquery.boxy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.print();
    });
</script>
........
...........
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing the Boxy plugin before jQuery. Re-order your script tags like this:

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/boxy/jquery.boxy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your jQuery script

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

loading successfully?

Try replacing it with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(loading jQuery from Google's web site) and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Is security enabled in your Asp.Net application. Mine was. Beacuse of it, jquery file cannot be loaded. Add below lines to your web.config:

```
<location path="JS">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```